# How do I transition to a new page after my aync call is complete in c# Xamarin form?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my startup (app.xaml.cs) in OnStart() method , I am using Acr.UserDialogs to show a Loading spinner whilst I retrieve the the data from the database.  I'm currently having an issue where when the Task  completes I expect it to transition to a new Page but this is not happening and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have the following code:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
        //showing the loading spinner here (Works)
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading ...", 
        MaskType.Black));

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            ProductsViewModel = await _storeService.GetProducts();
        })
            .ContinueWith(result => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                () =>
                    {

                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                    //once the data is received here, I expect this to transition to the ProductList 
                   //Page but it doesn't and I'm not sure why
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ProductList(ProductsViewModel));
                    
                })
            );
}
```

Could it because I'm blocking something?

Comment: Try to put ```await Task.Delay(100);``` after the ShowLoading line.

Comment: unfortunatly that did not work

Comment: Can't you just make `OnStart` async and then get rid of your `Task.Run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, We will have to initialize the MainPage in App class constructor. We can create a ContentPage object and can assign it to the MainPage. We are creating the Base Class (ContentPage) object so it will look like no change in UI.

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new ContentPage();
        }

protected override void OnStart()
    {
        //showing the loading spinner here (Works)
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading ...", 
        MaskType.Black));

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            ProductsViewModel = await _storeService.GetProducts();
        })
            .ContinueWith(result => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                () =>
                    {

                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                    //once the data is recieved here, I expect this to transition to the ProductList 
                   //Page but it doesn't and I'm not sure why
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ProductList(ProductsViewModel));
                    
                })
            );
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!